# Hive:Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

I wrote a `test.sql` file and ran it with hive. I got the error when hive was parsing to the code(show below):

```
[CODE]:
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION foo AS "com.mytest.udaf.HelloWorldFoo";

[ERROR]:
This query failes with the error: "Execution Error, return code -101 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask"
```

PS: Hadoop was running on Java 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason [here](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/cdh-user/1331vfw23w/cant-execute-custom-udf-udaf-on-beeswax-cdh-4-2).

The problem was that the UDAF class was compiled with Java 7 and Hadoop was
running on Java 6.